# How can I access a specific range of bytes in a file using Perl?

Tags: perl, file

What is the most convenient way to extract a specified byte range of a file on disk into a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`seek`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfunc#seek) to the start of the range, [`read`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfunc#read) the desired number of bytes (or `sysseek`/`sysread` -- see nohat's comment).

```
open $fh, '<', $filename;
seek $fh, $startByte, 0;
$numRead = read $fh, $buffer, $endByte - $startByte; # + 1
&do_something_with($buffer);
```

Comment: Why do you need to override the prototype checking on `do_something_with()`?

Comment: `$fh` hasn't been declared, if you `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Crikey - the OP asked for the most convenient way, not the most pedantic way.  ;-)

Comment: I think you mean `sysread $fh, $buffer, $endByte - $startByte +1;`

Comment: Also, the order of the parameters to seek is backwards. It's seek FILEHANDLE,POSITION,WHENCE so it should be `seek $fh, $startByte, 0`

Comment: Finally, this doesn't work because you can't mix `seek` calls with `sysread` calls. You need to use `sysseek` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I like to use [File::Map](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Map), which lazily loads a file into a scalar. That turns it into string operations instead of filehandle operations:

```
    use File::Map 'map_file';

    map_file my $map, $filename;

    my $range = substr( $map, $start, $length );
```